# Prove that if $f$ is injective, and $C$, $D ⊆ A$, then $f (C ∩ D) = f (C) ∩ f (D)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $f : A \rightarrow B$ be a function.
>   Prove that if $f$ is injective, and $C$, $D ⊆ A$, then $f(C ∩ D) = f(C) ∩ f(D)$.

My attempt so far, (might be incorrect, but It is my best so far):

> Assume that $f(x) ∈ f(C ∩ D)$, this implies that $x ∈ C ∩ D$.
>   By the definition of set intersection, $x ∈ C ∩ D$ means that $x ∈ C$ and $x ∈ D$.
>   The previous statement implies that $f(x) ∈ f(C)$ and $f(x) ∈ f(D)$.
>   If $f(x) ∈ f(C)$ and $f (x) ∈ f(D)$, it follows that $f(x) ∈ f(C) ∩ f(D)$.

Is this enough? And if so, how does the fact that *f* is injective helps with this proof?

Comment: You've proven $f(C\cap D)\subseteq f(C)\cap f(D)$. To prove equality, the next step is to assume $f(x)\in f(C)\cap f(D)$ and conclude that $f(x) \in f(C\cap D)$.

Comment: So basically I need to conclude the other way around to prove equality of the two sets?

Comment: Yes. It is the most common way to prove equality between two sets (i.e. both $X\subseteq Y$ and $Y\subseteq X$).

Comment: Injectivity helps because your first line does not follow without injectivity. If the function was not injective, then $f(x)$ could be in $f(C \cap D)$ without $x$ being in $C \cap D$, because $f(x)$ could be a member of $B$ mapped from some member of $A$ that is \not\ $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did:
$$
y \in f(C\cap D) \implies y\in f(C)\cap f(D)
$$

What remains:
$$
y\in f(C)\cap f(D)
 \implies y \in f(C\cap D)
 $$

So take $y\in f(C)\cap f(D)$. There is a representation $y = f(x_C)$ with $x_C\in C$, because $y\in f(C)$. And a representation $y = f(x_D)$ with $x_D\in D$, because $y\in f(D)$.

Now using injectivity, $x := x_C = x_D \in C\cap D$, so $y = f(x)\in f(C\cap D)$.